# Can we combine css selectors and react selectors in TestCafe?

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am currently working in react based application and I want to click on the element which is the combination of react selector and CSS selectors.

```
const app_ui = ReactSelector("AppUi")
const tmp = await app_ui.getReact();
const app_name = tmp.props.app.name
const tiles = app_name.Selector('.qa-card');
await t.hover(tiles).click(Selector('button').withText('Launch'))
```

TypeError: app_name.Selector is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `ReactSelector` and `Selector` to specify an element in your tests. 
Import them first and then use in a test, for example:

```js
import { ReactSelector } from 'testcafe-react-selectors';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`fixture`
    .page`http://url`;

test('test', async t => {
    //you can interact with app_ui as well as elements specified by Selector
    const app_ui = ReactSelector("AppUi");
    const tiles  = Selector('.qa-card');

    await t
        .hover(tiles)
        .click(Selector('button').withText('Launch'));
});
```

Note that the `getReact()` [method](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors#obtaining-components-props-and-state) returns an object containing a component's props, state and key.
Your component's `app.name` property cannot contain [TestCafe Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/).